# Automatically removing objects created by a loop once it's done

Tags: r, loops, memory, environment-variables

I know that loops are usually not the best, but I need to use them because I want to load CSV files sequentially and save them as RDS. (I don't want to load them at once

```
dataList <- c("iris","cars")
for(dataname in dataList) {
   data(list=dataname) 
   path <- paste0(getwd(),"/",dataname,".rds")
   saveRDS(dataname,path)
   rm(list=dataname) #ensures that datasets are not held in memory simultaneously
}
```

I wanted to know if it was possible to remove automatically objects that are created from this loop and/or put in memory, rather than having to do it manually

```
rm(dataname, path)
```

Comment: You could write a function to do the loading so that those objects you don't want to keep are not created in the global environment (and return only the objects you want to keep).

Comment: Run everything inside a `local({...})` statement and then garbage collect `gc()`.

Comment: @beginneR OTOH, if the OP is going to run into a memory limit, then he  needs to remove the files even inside the function.  However, to load random `csv` files I'd recommend `tempdata<-read.csv(dataname)`, `saveRDS(tempdata,path)` and `rm(dataname)` as cleaner code.